# Pyparsing setResultsName dynamically

Tags: pyparsing

I'm using `PyParsing` to parse a log file. The elements I want have the regular left aligned structure

```
 <key>:<value>
```

I can easily get the key parsed but crucially want to use this as arg to `setResultsName`. I think I've just satisfied myself that `pp.Forward()` is not the answer.

Can anyone provide one? Key point is the need to use as arg to `setResultsName` a string which becomes known only as the file is parsed.

Comment: There are several options in pyparsing for creating results names dynamically from the parsed data. Dict and dictOf are the most direct, and probably will do what you need. You could also define a parse action to do this, but check out the Dict and dictOf options first.

Comment: Paul thank you I'll take a look at those.